# Captureing screen size and creating overlay in HTML/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am creating a home page for a website and I am attempting to copy part of the background img to use as a nav link so i can manipulate it. When i design the page every thing will look good but when i view on different screens the overlay is thrown out of align.

I have tried to implement screen.width and screen.height, from JavaScript, to capture the sizes and pass them as a var into HTML code. Then i use HTML top % and left/right % 
to adjust the overlaying nav to match up with the background img.

```
<script>
        //capture the screen size 

            var w =screen.width;
            var h = screen.height;
        </script>

<style>
            body {
                background:url("screen.jpg")no-repeat left top fixed;
                background-size: w h;
            }           
            #b1{
                background-size: 180px 70px;
                background: no-repeat left top fixed;
                padding: 130px 50px;
                color: white;
                text-align: center;
                background-image: url("b1.png");
                margin: 0;
                position: absolute;
                top: 55.3%;
                left: 11.5%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Does anyone have a fix for this? is it a HTML or JavaScript issue?

Comment: How do you think that a variable defined in a language (JavaScript) can be known and processed by another (CSS)??

Comment: You can just use percentages...

Comment: That is where i am stuck. because when i view it on my PC its fine. After I upload it to the server it gets img distortion.

@ Lelio I am just trying to come up with ideas.
@motanelu I am usinging % based on the background size that there the top:55.3% comes in but it is still being distorted. even if i plug in the back ground size as like ex:1400 x 500

Answer (score 0):

@JohnLiebig a couple of things.  When you are working within CSS you should not be using HTML or JS related variables/methods.  If you would like to use CSS variables the formatting can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables).

The below snippet was found on MDN under ['background-size.'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

```
.foo {
  background-image: url(bg-image.png);

  -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;           /* Safari 3.0 */
     -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;           /* Gecko 1.9.2 (Firefox 3.6) */
       -o-background-size: 100% 100%;           /* Opera 9.5 */
          background-size: 100% 100%;           /* Gecko 2.0 (Firefox 4.0) and other CSS3-compliant browsers */

  -moz-border-image: url(bg-image.png) 0;    /* Gecko 1.9.1 (Firefox 3.5) */
}
```